# How to increment time in bash and run a command?

Tags: bash, shell

I am having a below command to be executed in bash

```
stats --var ds:sys:odx --diff --show --from 2019-03-28,05:45:33
```

I need to modify the --from time for every 1 minutes,sleep for a minute and then run the command.

I tried with below

```
for i in {46..59}; do declare x$i=$(stats --var ds:sys:odx --diff --show --from 2019-03-28,05:$i:00);done
```

How to add sleep and execute the command every 1 minutes interval?

Comment: Should the from time actually be the current time?  If so it would probably be better to obtain it from the date command

Comment: @Jesse_b Yes it should be current time , how to get the current time in that format?

Comment: I have updated my answer to include that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close but I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with the `x$i=$(` part.

Does the following work for you?

```
for i in {45..59}; do
    stats --var ds:sys:odx --diff --show --from "2019-03-28,05:${i}:00"
    sleep 60
done
```

---

If you would prefer to get the time dynamically you could do something like this:

```
for ((i=0; i<15; i++)); do
    stats --var ds:sys:odx --diff --show --from "$(date '+%F,%H:%M:%S')"
    sleep 60
done
```

This will run the command once a minute for 15 minutes grabbing the current date/time in the required format each time.

Comment: The second method throws an error as "the required argument for option '--from' is missing

Comment: @Samselvaprabu: What OS are you running/What version of `date` do you have?

Comment: Also does it want the hours in 24 hour clock or 12 hour clock?

Comment: it's a customized version of CentOS

Comment: If you just run `date '+%F,%H:%M:%S'` from the command line what does it return?

Comment: ERROR: Invalid option '+%F,%H:%M:%S'.
INFO: Use the --help option to view usage information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91656/discussion-between-samselvaprabu-and-jesse-b).

Comment: as first method is working , I mark it as an answer. Thanks for your quick help

Comment: as first method is working , I mark it as an answer. Thanks for your quick help